# How to show custom error while installing a Joomla! 1.6 - 1.7 component?

Tags: php, joomla, installation

I am writing an install script for a Joomla! 1.7 component. How can I modify the `install()` section of the script so that in case of failure, I can show the user a nicely formatted HTML error?

Currently, I only return `false` from the `install()` routine, which results in a cryptic error message:

> Component Install: Custom install routine failure

The component.php file in `joomla/installer/adapters/component.php` has the following code, which leads me to suspect that I can't change the `abort()` message.

```
if ($this->parent->manifestClass && method_exists($this->parent->manifestClass, 'install')) 
{
     if ($this->parent->manifestClass->install($this) === false) {
          // Install failed, rollback changes
          $this->parent->abort(JText::_('JLIB_INSTALLER_ABORT_COMP_INSTALL_CUSTOM_INSTALL_FAILURE'));
          return false;
     }
  }
```

**Solution**

Before returning an error, I can raise an error, that appears nicely in a yellow box.

```
JError::raiseNotice(1, "Error Message <html code>");
return false;
```

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, then select it as the best answer in case someone has this question again.

Comment: Shouldn't you be targeting Joomla 2.5 by now?

Comment: juanprozo: Most of users still use 1.5 and 1.6-1.7 So if you plan to hit wide audience - you have to support those versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

Before returning an error, I can raise an error, that appears nicely in a yellow box.

```
JError::raiseNotice(1, "Error Message <html code>");
return false;
```